# How to change icon at Navigation menu Bar at Andorid Studio?

Tags: android-studio, navigation, drawable, android-drawable

[My Image Please Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0nyH.png)

1. How to change the icon in red line? Is possible to change it with PNG Picture??
   I see the code is defined by pathdata,and I don't know the pathdata came from?
2. How I can make a "link" to a new .xml files? example , if I click the import,the system must be redirect to a.xml, if I click the slideshow menu, so system must redirect to b.xml??

thankyou everybody, and sorry im new in Android development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Just import the pictures you want in the folder /res/drawable for example and replace them with the original one in your xml code by specifying the path (@/drawable/mypicture). You can use PNG, JPG, and almost every format and pathdata surely is a predefined path containing thos pictures.

2.You can create new XML file in the folder /res/layout for example (you can also create personnal folders, it will work too) and then inside your application you can use :  setContentView(R.layout.myview) 
, to use your personnal XML if it is in the layout folder.